# How to process Avro input from Kafka (with Apache Beam) when there are multiple subjects on one topic?

Tags: apache-beam, avro, confluent-schema-registry, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

In order to process Avro-encoded messages with Apache Beam using [`KafkaIO`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/37f849593a1ce4c7005e0191f72f6a6418f25d6a/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java), one needs to pass an instance of [`ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/37f849593a1ce4c7005e0191f72f6a6418f25d6a/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.java) as the value deserializer.

A typical example looks like this:

```
PCollection<KafkaRecord<Long, GenericRecord>> input = pipeline
  .apply(KafkaIO.<Long, GenericRecord>read()
     .withBootstrapServers("kafka-broker:9092")
     .withTopic("my_topic")
     .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
     .withValueDeserializer(
         ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of("http://my-local-schema-registry:8081", "my_subject"))
```

However, some of the Kafka topics, that I want to consume, have multiple different subjects (event types) on them (for ordering reasons). Thus, I can't provide one fixed subject name in advance. How can this dilemma be solved?

(My goal is to, in the end, use [`BigQueryIO`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) to push these events to the cloud.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do multiple reads, one per subject, and then [Flatten](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten) them.

Comment: Ah, good idea, thanks. I'll try that and see how the skipped elements are handled (errors?) and how this plays out with the consumer offsets.

Comment: The non-decodable events are skipped, and regarding the offsets, I just set separate values for `group.id` using `.withConsumerConfigUpdates`. Thanks again. :)